# HTML img-tag height attribute gets ignored

Tags: html, image, pagespeed

I am doing website optimization using Chrome Pagespeed.

Pagespeed proposes that I set width and height attributes of img-tags.

However when i set the attributes like this:

```
<img src="xx.png" width="50" height="100" />
```

The height attribute is ignored on page render. The height get's the same size as the width attribute. Do you guys have any insights on why this is?

Using inline style do render the page correctly, but it does not solve the problem according to Chrome Pagespeed.

I hope that I have made my question clear enough.

EDIT:
I am using HTML5. According to w3schools.com/tags/att_img_height.asp, height should be in pixels (with no unit definition).

Thank you in advance,
fischer

Comment: Please post a complete demo (HTML + CSS) that reproduces the problem and specify the browser(s) tested. Either your real markup isn’t what you posted here, or there is something on the page that causes the problem.

Comment: If, as you say, "Using inline style do render the page correctly", there is something in the stylesheet that sets the height. Inline styles override the stylesheet, but attributes do not. Especially be on the lookout for "reset" type styles such as  `* {height:auto}`.

Comment: By the way, "Inspect Element" (or similar tools in other browsers) will tell you where the specific styles for an element are defined exactly. Also, if Google Pagespeed really suggests to use attributes here, maybe you should take its advice with a grain of salt.

Comment: [Please, don't link to or use w3schools. It's a horrible reference full of incorrect information that sometimes even leads to security holes.](http://w3fools.com)